# Is it possible to take SVN update on remote server if SVN repository is setup on local machine?

Tags: svn, remote-server

I have setup SVN repository on server located in our LAN. We can access it easily over LAN, But is their anyway to checkout or svn update of the code on remote server if both servers are connected with internet.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways, but all of the ways are sensitive to how the two machines are connected.  Some networking setups prevent this type of coordination form happening.  For example, a firewall that is neither the remote server or the local server could prevent access between the two.

First you would need the remote machine to have some sort of network access to the SVN server it wanted to coordinate with.

Provided that the remote server is acting like a typical SVN user, it would checkout the code, and submit changes.

If the remote server was supposed to provide SVN services to other remote clients, then you need to diverge your checkout strategies from your checkin strategies (or you will quickly get two SVN servers with different histories).

This might mean a "remote read only" server for faster checkouts, with all check-ins going to the single "master" SVN server.

Comment: I think you are probably overcomplicating things. I would imagine the OP means "remote host" when they write "remote server", not really a second SVN server.

Comment: @tripleee Well, with an unclear description of what is required, I tend to answer in a general way with a few guesses at what was asked, and specific details tied to those guesses.  Sure, the asker might mean "remote host" which is covered; but, it is a common thing to setup  remote server for ease of development at a remote location.  You get fast checkouts, reduced expensive transcontinental bandwidth, and a lot of features which are valuable enough that such a setup is more common than one might believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sure you can. Do you have remote access to the server? All you would need to do is do an svn checkout of the local repository using the file:/// protocol.

For example, if your repository is located at `/svn/myrepo`

you can do an svn checkout with

```
svn co file:///svn/myrepo/trunk /path/to/working/directory
```

And then you can work from your directory as normal. This is a linux/unix example but the same applies to Windows with `file:///C:/svn/myrepo`